# which is better? asp.net 2.0 stick with isapi rewrite or upgrade to 3.5 and use mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, url-rewriting, asp.net-2.0

i have a asp.net 2.0 web app that runs with ajax 1.0 extensions and isapi rewrite.

I have some bugs and i am considering whether to upgrade to 3.5 and use asp.net mvc instead.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade your framework version to .NET 3.5 SP1. Use the System.Web.Routing namespace and you'll get MVC's URL routing functionality. You don't need to completely switch over to MVC from WebForms.

Comment: by upgrade the framework version, you mean upgrade the server framework. What about the code of the web application? Please forgive me. I am quite the noob.

Comment: You should only need to upgrade the server framework. Despite the version number change, .Net 3.5 SP1 uses the same core runtime as .Net 2.0.  The code should still just work.

Comment: You will need to install .NET 3.5 SP1 and Visual Studio 2008 SP1 (if you're using Visual Studio). Then you'll get the new System.Web.Routing.dll installed.

Answer (score 1):

I would upgrade to WebForms 3.5 (.NET 3.5 SP1). Routing was baked into .NET 3.5 SP1.
After that if you find that you want to use some of the other features of MVC then you could upgrade then. Here's an [MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.01.extremeaspnet.aspx) that should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

If your of the elk that enjoys rewriting your entire project because some new geewiz technology comes out then go for it (I know I am). If not, stick to what you have. MVC Framework is great but rewriting code will almost always cause you more problems then fixing the exsisting bug you have.

Answer (score 0):

100% Asp.Net MVC is better than WebForms and it does no matter 2.0 or 3.5.
Just try and you will understand my point :)